# How can I update a NuGet package in multiple solutions without manually opening the solutions?

Tags: powershell, nuget

We use the Entity Framework 6.1.2 NuGet package in 6 solutions. EF was just updated to 6.1.3 and we want to update all of the solutions to use the newest version. Taking the naive route we would open a solution in Visual Studio, use the NuGet Package Manager to update the package, close the solution, repeat for next solution. Running `Update-Package EntityFramework` in the Package Manager Console is probably a little more efficient than using the GUI but still requires opening each solution individually.

I'd love to be able to run a script which finds all the solutions in a folder and updates the package for (all projects in) each solution. I realize that updating the version number in the packages.config is not the same as installing the new version of a package, so that (very simple) option won't work. I also realize that there's not much efficiency to be gained by doing this one time, but libraries are updated so frequently these days keeping up to date can become an (admittedly minor) annoyance. Is it possible to automate this task?